# Problem in understanding 'order' property in css

Tags: html, css, css-grid

[image]

This is my HTML code for this

```
<section class="block container">
  <article class="grid grid--1x2 feature">
    <div class="feature__content">
      <span class="icon-container">
        <svg class="icon icon--primary">
          <use xlink:href="../images/sprite.svg#easy"></use>
        </svg>
      </span>
      <h3 class="feature__heading">Super Easy to Use</h3>
      <p class="">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Consectetur, vitae facilis quo eligendi pariatur quia non culpa
        animi voluptatibus optio?
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="link-arrow">Learn More</a>
    </div>
    <img class="feature__image" src="images/easy@1x.png" alt="" />
  </article>
</section>
```

This is grid layout. I want to show the image in the left side. For this my css code is like below

```
.feature:nth-of-type(1) .feature__content {
    order: 2;
  }
```

This works.

[image]

But if use this code below this does not work.

```
.feature:nth-of-type(1) .feature__image {
    order: 1;
  }
```

I want to understand why this is not working. Isn't it the same thing?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the rest of the CSS applied to the HTML. It would be nice if you could use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) to create a [mre] directly in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the same thing. The default `order` value is 0, as specified in MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

When you assign `order: 2` to `.feature__content` you're telling it to appear as the last element. When you assign `order: 1` to `.feature__image` you're telling it to appear after the elements with `order: 0`.

That's why it doesn't work, and it appears unchanged. To make it work you'd need to define `.feature__content` to `order: 1` at least. Or maybe put some negative number into `.feature__image` such as `order: -1`

Answer (score -2):

Your image outside of  
Put image inside of  “.feature__content” div

Comment: Is this intended to be an answer? It's not clear what you're suggesting. Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Comment: See also [answer].

Comment: Of course it is. If they weren't siblings then they couldn't have their positions in the grid swapped (because only one of them would be positioned on the grid in the first place)